# Is it theoretically possible to achieve JIT compilation of windows drivers into linux drivers in order to bypass complex proprietary windows drivers?

Tags: linux, windows, driver, linux-device-driver

I would suspect such a method might not even expose much from an engineering standpoint from the architecture and hence to not even be intrusive to the involved entity's intellectual property.

Comment: Really? You don't understand what I'm saying? Be more honest next time: You are against it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, because the JIT compiler would have to compile that code in real time first, and since drivers hook into the kernel, the kernel would be the only real program that could do that, and since this arrives the possibility of security issues I would imagine such a scenario would not be practical.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for that being impossible in general is that the internal **kernel API** is **different**, even conceptually, between Windows and Linux.

So in general a Windows driver is based on resources  and functions that are Windows specific (and vice-versa).

<sup>Some clever people could do an `ndiswrapper` but I guess they had to simulate the Windows kernel specific API for wifi...; doing that for other types of drivers (graphics, ...) may be practically impossible.</sup>

A practical advice is to avoid buy hardware without Linux drivers (preferably free software ones). This put a market pressure on hardware manufacturers.